# PowerShell remove last column of pipe delimited text file

Tags: powershell

I have a folder of pipe delimited text files that I need to remove the last column on. I'm not seasoned in PS but I found enough through searches to help. I have two pieces of code. The first creates new text files in my destination path, keeps the pipe delimiter, but doesn't remove the last column. There are 11 columns. Here is that script:

```
$OutputFolder = "D:\DC_Costing\Vendor Domain\CostUpdate_Development_Load_To_IMS"

ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem "D:\DC_Costing\Vendor Domain\CostUpdate_Development_Stage_To_IMS\*.txt")) 
{
(Get-Content $File) | Foreach-Object { $_.split()[0..9] -join '|' } | Out-File $OutputFolder\$($File.Name)
}
```

Then this second code I tried creates the new text files on my destination path, it DOES get rid of the last column, but it loses the pipe delimiter. Ugh.

```
$OutputFolder = "D:\DC_Costing\Vendor Domain\CostUpdate_Development_Load_To_IMS"

ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem "D:\DC_Costing\Vendor Domain\CostUpdate_Development_Stage_To_IMS\*.txt")) 
{
Import-Csv $File -Header col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11 -Delimiter '|' | 
Foreach-Object {"{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9}" -f $_.col1,$_.col2,$_.col3,$_.col4,$_.col5,$_.col6,$_.col7,$_.col8,$_.col9,$_.col10} | Out-File $destination\$($File.Name)
}
```

I have no clue on what I'm doing wrong. I have no preference in which way I get this done but I need to keep the delimiter and the have the last column removed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just need to change the line on `foreach-object`, like `{0}|{1}|{2}...` so replace the spaces for pipes

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot for your quick response. It makes total sense looking at it now but I couldn't find any text on this anywhere and I had been going through online posts all morning. Thanks again Santiago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plain-text processing attempt with `Get-Content`, you simply need to split each line by `|` first (`.Split('|')`), before extracting the fields of interest with a range operation (`..`) and joining them back with `|`:

```
Get-Content $File | 
  Foreach-Object { $_.Split('|')[0..9] -join '|' } |
    Out-File $OutputFolder\$($File.Name)
```

---

In your `Import-Csv`-based attempt, you can take advantage of the fact that it will only read as many columns as you supply column names for, via `-Header`:

```
# Pass only 10 column names to -Header
Import-Csv $File -Header (0..9).ForEach({ 'col' + $_ }) -Delimiter '|' | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' | # convert back to CSV with delimiter '|'
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |  # skip the header row
      Out-File $destination\$($File.Name)
```

Note that [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv), just like `Export-Csv` by default *double-quotes* each field in the resulting CSV data / file.

In Windows PowerShell, you cannot avoid this, but in PowerShell (Core) 7+ you can control this behavior with `-UseQuotes Never`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. All of these answers can and would be accepted as the answer. The Get-Content for some reason I like over the the import/export csv. Not sure why but maybe because it looks cleaner? Appreciate your response.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @tompratt. Plain-text processing with `Get-Content` is faster than an `Import-Csv` solution, but the latter is more robust (which may not be needed in your case), because it can handle field values with _embedded_ `|` chars., for instance, because it handles double-quoted fields correctly. Also, given that `Import-Csv` gives you _objects_ to work with, it is much more flexible with respect to processing the data (in case you need more than just to save back to a file).

Comment: Out of curiosity and possible future need will any of these work with an .xlsx file or files? i haven't tried yet but was just wondering. thanks.

Comment: @tompratt, no, you'll need a dedicated module that can read Excel files; a popular choice is the third-party [`ImportExcel`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try, should be more efficient than using `Import-Csv`, however note, this should always exclude the **last column of your files no matter how many columns they have** and assuming they're **pipe delimited**:

```
$OutputFolder = "D:\DC_Costing\Vendor Domain\CostUpdate_Development_Load_To_IMS"

foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem "D:\DC_Costing\Vendor Domain\CostUpdate_Development_Stage_To_IMS\*.txt")) {
    [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($File.FullName) | & {
        process{
            -join ($_ -split '(?=\|)' | Select-Object -SkipLast 1)
        }
    } | Set-Content (Join-Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $File.Name)
}
```

Comment: Works just fine. I obviously need to learn PowerShell better but it's nice to have your seasoned pros on here to give guidance. It's not my main bread and butter at work but PowerShell definitely has it's perks. Thank you again.